Ошибка на сайте при запуске на сервере
Всем доброго времени суток. Я разрабатываю сайт на Python с использованием Flask. Сайт на локальном компьюторе работает отлично, но на сервере он почему то не открывает страницу /edds. Никак не могу разобраться в чем дело. В логах выводит следующее:
2024-08-28 08:12:32,350 - __main__ - ERROR - Ошибка в функции edds_inner: -1

Код логов:
def log_errors(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            logger.info(f'Функция {func.__name__} выполнена успешно')
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'Ошибка в функции {func.__name__}: {e}')
            raise
    return wrapper

Код страницы:
@app.route('/edds', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edds():
    @log_errors
    def edds_inner():
        global db
        if 'username' in session:
            if session['premison'] == 'EDDS' or session['premison'] == 'ADMIN':
                    login = session['fullname']
                    if request.method == "GET":
                        # date_input = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
                        date_input = ""
                        main = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,* FROM main_table WHERE strftime('%Y', date_main) >= strftime('%Y', 'now', '-2 year') ORDER BY date_main DESC").fetchall()
                        request_edds = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,* FROM edds_request WHERE strftime('%Y', date) >= strftime('%Y', 'now', '-2 year') ORDER BY date DESC").fetchall()
                        level_water = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,value,date value,date FROM level_water WHERE strftime('%Y', date) >= strftime('%Y', 'now', '-2 year') ORDER BY date DESC").fetchall()
                        row_statistic = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,Gosnas, message_manager, data data FROM row_statistic WHERE strftime('%Y', data) >= strftime('%Y', 'now', '-2 year') ORDER BY data DESC")
                        # date_input = datetime.datetime.now().date()
                    else:
                        date_input = request.form['date_input']
                        main = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,* FROM main_table WHERE date_main == \'{date_input}\'").fetchall()
                        request_edds = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,* FROM edds_request WHERE date = \'{date_input}\'").fetchall()
                        level_water = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,value,date FROM level_water WHERE date == \'{date_input}\'").fetchall()
                        row_statistic = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT ROWID,Gosnas, message_manager, data FROM row_statistic WHERE data == \'{date_input}\'").fetchall()
                        # date_input = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_input, '%Y-%m-%d') 
                    data = {
                        
                        'title':'ЕДДС',
                        'date_input':date_input
                    }
                    all_info = []
                    start =time.perf_counter()
                    convert = {
                        'FIRE':"Пожары",
                        'FIRED':"Загорания",
                        'DTP':"ДТП",
                        'BEACH':'На воде в купальный сезон',
                        'WATER':"На воде (прочие проишествия)",
                        "OBJECT":"На обьектах жизниобеспечения",
                        "NATURAL":'Природные',
                        "TECH":'Техногенные',
                        "BIOSOC":"Биолого-социальные",
                        "TERRACT":"Теракты",
                        "FAKE_CALL":"Ложные вызовы",


                    }
                    convert2 = {
                        0:'При неосторожном обращении с огнем (Пожар)',
                        1:"Причина устанвливается (Пожар)",
                        2:"Из-за неисправности печи (Пожар)",
                        3:'При нарушении правил пожарной безопасности (Пожар)',
                        4:"Не справился с управлением (ДТП)",
                        5:"При столкновении (ДТП)",
                        6:"При опрокидывании автомобиля (ДТП)",
                        7:"Наезд на пешехода (ДТП)",
                        8:"Утонули по личной неосторожности во время купания (На воде)",
                        9:"Несчастный случай на рыбалке (На воде)",
                        10:"Суицид (На воде)",
                        11:"Не Счастный случай (На воде)",
                        12:"При поражении электричестком (Несчастный случай)",
                        13:"При нарушение экспулатации др. печи (Несчастный случай)"

                    }
                    for i in [main,request_edds,level_water, row_statistic]:
                        for j in i:
                            if isinstance(j[1],str):
                                j=list(j)
                                j[1] = convert[j[1]]
                                all_info.append(j)
                            elif len(j) == 16:
                                row = []
                                row.append(j[0])
                                row.append(convert2[j.index(max(j[1:-2]))-1])
                                row.append(j[j.index(max(j[1:-2]))])
                                row.append(j[-2])
                                row.append(j[-1])
                                all_info.append(row)
                            else:
                                all_info.append(j)
                    data['data'] = all_info
                    print('Loading EDDS list',time.perf_counter()-start)
                    #all_info = sorted(all_info, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
                    
                    
                    return render_template('edds_list.html',data=data)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('main_method'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('main_method'))
    return edds_inner()

Прошу помощи. Хотел бы разобраться что вообще за ошиюка такая "-1" и какие возможные причины того, что локально сайт работает отлично, а на сервере уже имеются некоторые проблемы.

Что-то я не вижу - а где у вас вообще эта функция edds_inner вызывается, собственно? И кстати вы .fetchall() забыли в первом вычислении row_statistic.

@CrazyElf я использую return edds_inner внутри функции edds

А, ну да, я слепой )  Как-то это выглядит просто странно. Надо ещё посмотреть
